# Any Casperjs version where phantomjs is not prerequisite

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i had several year ago casperjs installed but by mistake i deleted the path with casperjs and i am almost sure that this version did not use phantojs!
I searched also to find a path with phantojs on my server (Linux) but couldn't find it.

The only information that i have is that the path with casperjs was:

/share/n1k0-casperjs-cd1fab5

But i searched in the repository of casperjs and i could not figure out which version it is!

So, do you know maybe which casperjs has not prerequisite phantomjs?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't accepted many answers yet. Please go through your questions and see if the given answers actually answer your question and can be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

CasperJS can only be used with either PhantomJS or SlimerJS:

https://slimerjs.org/faq.html

> Q: Can CasperJS be launched with SlimerJS?
>   A: Yes, since SlimerJS 0.8, and with CasperJS 1.1beta1 or higher. Just launch CasperJS as usual by adding --engine=slimerjs on the command line.